# Reactjs Weback Error: Cannot find module './lib/bootstrap.loader!./no-op.js'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am learning reactjs with webpack. I found a error while i add
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in my `index.js`

I have successfully installed bootstrap loader but not getting why this error i am seeing.

***I notice some question previously asked many people but those problem couldnt solve my problem, please don't report it as duplicate question***

this is my webpack:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader", "bootstrap-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "bootstrap-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

the error fired:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module './lib/bootstrap.loader!./no-op.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR in ./node\_modules/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403728/error-in-node-modules-bootstrap-loader-no-op-js)

Comment: Please delete your comment, those solution i seen but they didnt solve my issue

Comment: those solution couldnt solve my issue